# Trying to display top 10 scores - Only getting one result

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I'm trying to create a leaderboards page which shows the top 10 users depending on how much money they have.  The code that I have created works, but only shows one result -- the user with the most money. The problem is probably something simple, but I can't find anything to help.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

include "globals.php";

print "
<div class='generalinfo_txt'>
<div><img src='images/info_left.jpg' alt='' /></div>
<div class='info_mid'><h2 style='padding-top:10px;'> Leaderboards </h2></div>
<div><img src='images/info_right.jpg' alt='' /></div> </div>
<div class='generalinfo_simple'><br> <br><br>";

$q=$db->query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY money DESC LIMIT 10;");
print "<table width=75% cellspacing=1 class='table'> <tr style='background:gray;'> <th>Username</th> <th>User Level</th><th>Amount</th> </tr>";
while($r=$db->fetch_row($q))
{
$money=money_formatter($r['money']);
print "<tr><td>{$r['username']}";
print "</td><td>{$r['level']}</td><td>{$money}</td></tr>";
print "</table></div><div><img src='images/generalinfo_btm.jpg' alt='' /></div><br></div></div></div></div></div>";
}
$h->endpage();
?>
```

Comment: This probably isn't it, but what if you try `while $r=$q->fetch_row()`? Also I assume you get 10 rows back if you try this from the mysql interface directly, right?

Comment: Changing code makes no change, same output. And yes that is correct when running the query in MYSQL I get back 10 results.

Comment: Your code would be easier to read -- for us, and for you also -- if you formatted it better. Make the source lines shorter, so they fit within the screen area. Indent the lines inside of `<div>..</div>` and of `{..}` bodies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see a flaw in the code here. Your line:

```
print "</table></div><div><img src='images/generalinfo_btm.jpg' alt='' /></div><br></div></div></div></div></div>";
```

should be after the `while` loop, not inside it. As it is, you get broken HTML and you finish the table after the first result is printed.

Comment: Thank you! It's strange how you can be coding complex sites and something small like this can pass your eyes! Thanks again for everyone's response, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

you're using fetch_row which will pull only one record, do you mean to use fetch_array to pull all 10 records?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method database::fetch_array()

Comment: you could bypass the $db->query function since it does not include fetch_array and use "while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {" ... either that or research the $db->query class/object you are using and see if there is another method to pull the full record set instead a single row.

Comment: The `fetch_row()` call is part of a loop, so it gets called repeatedly.  That's not the problem.